# Creating a temporal train test split for customer item interactions

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I'm looking for a more pythonic/faster way to do this. The data consist of 6 million rows and there are around 8 columns. Any help much appriciated.

```py
data.sort_values(by=['user_id', 'event_time'], inplace=True)
data.reset_index(inplace=True)

unique_users_df = data['user_id'].unique()

train = pd.DataFrame()
test = pd.DataFrame()

for i, user in enumerate(unique_users_df):
    df = data[data['user_id'] == user]
    number = len(df)
    if number <= 5:
        pass
else:
    train_split = int(number * 0.80)
    test_split = int(number * 0.20)
    train_items = df.iloc[:train_split, :]
    test_items = df.iloc[-test_split:, :]
    train = pd.concat([train, train_items])
    test = pd.concat([test, test_items])
```

Comment: `sklearn` already have this function: [GroupShuffleSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupShuffleSplit.html)

Comment: Will that not shuffle the data? The Test has to be products viewed after the train split.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of your input to get help.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user':['ali', 'ali', 'ali', 'reza', 'reza'], 'feat':[1,2,3,1,2]})
train = df.groupby('user')['feat'].apply(list).apply(lambda x: x[:int(.8*len(x))])
test = df.groupby('user')['feat'].apply(list).apply(lambda x: x[int(.8*len(x)):])
```

Output:

[image]
[image]

Or, more simple:

```
train = df.groupby('user')['feat'].apply(lambda x: list(x)[:int(.8*len(x))])
```